# How to find a matrix D with m rows and n columns, with entries 1 and -1 only, which det(D'*D)=512

Tags: matlab, octave

I have created a 5x4 matrix with entries only 1 and -1. I have also created the code which gives me randomly possible configurations for this kind of matrix. Every time I check manually if the determinant of the D'*D product is equal to 512 or not. Until now, I have only got the results of determinants 0, +-64, 192 and +-128.

I want to get the matrix configurations automatically:
whose determinant is equal to 512,
whose determinant is between 0 and 512.

So far I have done this line of code. It is right, even though I have to run the code by myself after each calculation.

```
valueset = [1,-1];
desiredsize = [5, 4];
desiredmatrix = valueset(randi(numel(valueset), desiredsize))
b=desiredmatrix.'
a=desiredmatrix.'*D
det(a)
```

and I got these kinds of calculations:

```
>desired

desiredmatrix =

   1  -1   1  -1
   1  -1   1  -1
  -1  -1   1  -1
   1  -1  -1  -1
   1   1  -1  -1

b =

   1   1  -1   1   1
  -1  -1  -1  -1   1
   1   1   1  -1  -1
  -1  -1  -1  -1  -1

a =

   1   3   3   1
  -1   1  -3  -5
  -1  -3   1   3
  -3  -1  -5  -3

ans = 64
> desired

desiredmatrix =

  -1   1   1   1
   1   1   1   1
  -1  -1   1   1
   1  -1  -1  -1
   1  -1  -1  -1

b =

  -1   1  -1   1   1
   1   1  -1  -1  -1
   1   1   1  -1  -1
   1   1   1  -1  -1

a =

   3   1   1  -1
  -3  -1  -1   1
  -1  -3   1   3
  -1  -3   1   3

ans = 0
```

etc, etc

Comment: I didn't understand your question... But I tested `desiredsize = [6, 5]` else and it worked... I got some answers 512

Comment: @Joao_PS sorry for not questioning right. Precisely the size of the matrix must be 5 rows and 4 columns. All I want to do is to make the computer work for me, and not press the run button after each calculation ahahaha. Thank you for your answer

Comment: From the tag descriptions of both tags: _"Don’t use both the [tag:matlab] and [tag:octave] tags, unless the question is explicitly about the similarities or differences between the two"_

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It takes me around 23 milliseconds to compute first such matrix. And about 29-30 seconds to find all such matrices.

Now, we have 20 values in a matrix, so we have `2^20=1048576` such matrices.

So I run a for loop first to iterate through all these numbers (0 to 1048575). Now we go to fill the matrix. Now each `i` in the first for loop, I take the binary representation of `i` and pad it with 0s till I get a 20-element binary list.

So, `140` whose binary is `10001100` will become a list of `0000 0000 0000 1000 1100` (spaces added for visibility) which will be,
`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 0]` (say its named `bin_list`)

Now, to fill the 20 elements of my matrix (say 0 to 19) I fill
the jth element as `valueset[bin_list[j]]` so if the element of `bin_list` is 0, the corresponding element of my array A is 1 and if its 1 then A gets the value (-1). So, for the case of `140`, the matrix A will be

```py
[[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
 [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
 [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
 [-1,  1,  1,  1],
 [-1, -1,  1,  1]]
```

**Note: I have to convert A into a matrix using `numpy.matrix` since we need to calculate transpose and determinant.
This is depreciated as pointed out by user S Guogeon. So, for matrix multiplication, one can directly use `@` instead of `*` with `numoy.array`**

After calculating this matrix A, I calculate the transpose using `numpy.transpose()`, say it is B. now I calculate the determinant using `numpy.linalg.det(B*A)`. Now due to the return datatype of `numpy.linalg.det()`, I round it off to the nearest integer.

I check if this determinant is 512. If it is, bingo, I have the correct matrix.

The first solution I have is `854` `(i=854)`
The `bin_list` for this would be,
`[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0]`

The matrix `A` would be,

```py
matrix([[ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1,  1,  1],
       [ 1,  1, -1, -1],
       [ 1, -1,  1, -1],
       [ 1, -1, -1,  1]])
```

`A'*A` will be,

```py
matrix([[5, 1, 1, 1],
        [1, 5, 1, 1],
        [1, 1, 5, 1],
        [1, 1, 1, 5]])
```

The determinant of this will be 512 (after converting the determinant into an int)

The code for converting 140 to the binary list is:

```
def int_to_binlist(n, b = 8):
    res=[]
    strb = str(b)+'b'
    str1 = format(n, strb)
    res = list(map(int, list(str1)))
    return res
```

The code snippet for filling the matrix A with the bits of 1 and -1 is,

```
n_mat = desiredsize[0]*desiredsize[1] #so 5*4=20
for j in range(n_mat):
    a[int(j/4)][j%4] = valueset[li[j]]
```

References:
[numpy.linalg.det documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.linalg.det.html#numpy.linalg.det)
[numpy.matrix documentation](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html#numpy.matrix)

Comment: 1) `numpy.matrix` is deprecated, they no longer recommend its use. You can use a regular array to do the same things, you just need to use `@` instead of `*`. 2) Python is not MATLAB or Octave.

Comment: `2^20=1048576`, not `2048`

Comment: Oh right, my bad, I'll update the answer to reflect the changes regarding ``numpy.mstrix`` and the errorenous calculation of ``2^20`` .

Comment: @chris luengo, when i had originally answered the question, it mentioned python specifically, the edits and the tags to the question were added after I had answered.

Comment: The [tag:python] tag was removed at 21:23Z on Jan 7, well before you answered at 00:40Z on Jan 8. Nevertheless, the code in the question should have been a clue that this isn't python. Unfortunately, some people tend to spam their questions with irrelevant tags.

Comment: @PranavHosangadi I had the idea to accept solutions even in python, since I feel comfortable with that language too. I am new to this community and this are things that may happen. Sorry if my actions were missleading.